# How to access another computer by its User name and Password using ASP.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Here i have problem were, i want process start an application from computer A, using ASP.net C#. But the computer A is have authentication requirement, which is UserName = computerA and Password = computerA123. The computer A ip address is 192.168.4.10.

If i'm using normal program which is;

```
{
Process.Start(@"\\192.168.4.10\Document\testing.pdf")
}
```

It cannot work, it need authentication for allowed access the computer A.

Can anyone help me how include the authentication requirement into the program, for it freely access the computer A.

Comment: Side note: using Process.Start in ASP.Net frequently indicates lack of understanding how web sites implemented with ASP.Net work. Please consider adding sentence about you actual goal to show that you understand what result `Process.Start` will actually provide.

Comment: asp.net is a web application framework and too access a file means to download it. The downloading of file should simply require forms authentication from a login form..It seems you're trying to use adobe reader from someone else's machine..

Answer (score 0):

You should provide access to your PC IIS user account on computer A
e.g share it. (Assuming both of them are on the same domain)
For example:
If your PC is computer Z and you want to access a file on computer A.
Provide access right to ComputerZ\IIS_USR on that particular folder in Computer A